# What are the maximal ideals $M$ of $R = \mathbb{F}_{p^n}[X,Y]/(XY - 1)$? What is the degree of $R/M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R = \mathbb{F}_{p^n}[X,Y]/(XY - 1)$.

1. What are the maximal ideals $M$ of $R$?
2. What does $R/M$ look like? What is it's degree over $\mathbb{F}_p$?

There is a theorem that states that for every $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra $R$ of finite type and every maximal ideal $M \subset R$, $R/M$ is a finite field of characteristic $p$.

Now I thought that the ring $R$ above is actually a field isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}(X)$. Since it's a field the only maximal ideal is the trivial one and hence $R/M = R / \{0\} \cong R$. But that is not finite which seems to contradict the theorem. Where did I go wrong?

By the way I haven't yet found a proof of the mentioned theorem.

Comment: $R$ is the ring of Laurent polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. It is not a field since it has many non-invertible elements, such as $1 + X$. You don't need the theorem you cite if you understand the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}[X]$ and know some basic things about localization.

Comment: See if you can show that $R$ is naturally isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}[X]_X$, i.e., the polynomial ring with $X$ inverted. Then use the relationship between prime ideals before and after inverting something to relate these to a particular set of the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}[X]$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I realised $R$ is isomorphic to the polynomial ring with $X$ inverted, but mistakenly concluded that it was hence a field.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to write down an answer to an unanswered question. I'm also trying to clear to myself out some "obvious" things, as the **proof**, and write them down, so  please feel free to comment about anything in this post.

Putting $\,I:=\langle\,1-xy\,\rangle\,$ , define 
$$f:R\longrightarrow \mathbb F_{p^n}[x,x^{-1}]\,\,,\,\,f(g(x,y)+I):=g(x,x^{-1})$$

*$\,f\,$ is well defined*: $$g(x,y)+I=h(x,y)+I\Longrightarrow g(x,y)-h(x,y)=t(x,y)(xy-1)\Longrightarrow$$
$$ g(x,x^{-1})-h(x,x^{-1})=t(x,x^{-1})(xx^{-1}-1)=0\Longrightarrow g(x,x^{-1})=h(x,x^{-1})$$ 
$\,f\,$ is clearly a homomorphism of rings, and $\,g(x,x^{-1})=0\stackrel{(**)}\Longleftrightarrow g(x,y)\in I\,$ , from which we get that $\,f\,$ is bijective and thus an isomorphism.

**Proof of $\,(**)\,$ above:** let 
$$g(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^ma_k(x)y^k\in \mathbb K[x][y]\cong \mathbb K[x,y]\,\,,\,\mathbb K=\,\text{any field}$$and write 
$$a_k(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n_k}a_{ki}x^i\,\,,\,\,n_k\in\mathbb N\,\,,\,a_{ki}\in\mathbb K$$
Suppose $\,g(x,x^{-1})\equiv 0\,\,\,\text{in}\,\,\,\mathbb K[x,x^{-1}]$ . This means

$$g(x,x^{-1})=a_{0,0}+...+a_{0,n_0}x^{n_0}+x^{-1}\left(a_{1,0}+...+a_{1,n_1}x^{n_1}\right)+\ldots +x^{-m}\left(a_{n,0}+\ldots +a_{n,n_m}x^{n_m}\right)$$

The above expression being identically zero means that for any $\,k\in\mathbb N\,$ , we have
$$I\;\;\;\text{coefficient of}\,\,\,x^{-k}=a_{k,0}+a_{k+1,1} +\ldots +a_{j,j-k}+...=0$$ 
$$II\;\;\;\!\!\text{coefficient of}\,\,\,x^k\,\,=a_{0,k}+a_{1,k+1} +\ldots +a_{k,k+j}+...=0$$

The above sums are for sure finite, as there's only a finite number of powers (negative and positive) of $\,x\,$ with non-zero coefficients (this follows directly from the definition of ring of Laurent polynomials, of course).

Thus, going back to $\,g(x,y)\,$ and taking the sum of monomials with the above coefficients, we get 
$$a_{m,0}x^m+a_{m+1,1}x^{m+1}y+\ldots +a_{m+k,k}x^{m+k}y^k=x^m\left(a_{m,0}+a_{m+1,1}xy+...+a_{m+k,k}x^ky^k\right)=$$
$$\stackrel{by\,\,I}=x^m\left(-a_{m+1,1}-a_{m+2,2}-\ldots -a_{m+k,k}+a_{m+1,1}xy+\ldots a_{m+k,k}x^ky^k\right)=$$
$$=-x^m\left[a_{m+1,1}(1-xy)+a_{m+2,2}(1-x^2y^2)+...+a_{m+k,k}(1-x^ky^x)\right]\in I=\langle \,1-xy\,\rangle$$
since $\,1-x^ty^t=(1-xy)\left(1+xy+...+x^{t-1}y^{t-1}\right)\,$ . (The same argument works for the sum of monomials belonging to $\,II\,$ above)